# How to shift table location using .plot(table = True) for Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Currently I am using .plot(table=True) to display the tables and this is my current output:

[image]

May I know how can I shift the table down?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['month']).year
df.head()

ax = df.groupby(['year', 'child_gender'])['birth_count'].count().unstack('child_gender').fillna(0).plot(
    kind='line',
    stacked=False,
    marker='o',
    table = True)


plt.xticks(np.arange(2016,2019,1))
plt.legend(title='Child Gender', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.ylabel('Birth Count')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.title("Total Birth Count By Child Gender")
plt.autoscale(enable=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

this is the current dataframe I have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Use bbox

dont use table=True, instead create a table under the plot using plt.table

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,8))
df.plot(ax=ax)

plt.table(cellText=df.values,
                  loc='center left',
                  rowLabels=['f','m'],
                  colLabels=['2016','2017','2018'],
                  bbox=[0.0, -0.2, 1, 0.1])
```

Using second value in bbox list you can move it as much as you want

Comment: I am getting an error:
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'bbox'

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am not familiar on how to use plt.table(). May I know how can I populate the cell text with my current dataframe? I have included the data frame above.

Comment: I updated the answer It. df.values is your current df values